# how to set well formed numeric value

Tags: php

I am trying to find difference between two dates (one is user registration  date and another is current date). When the current date will be more then one day from registration date then the message will pop up "you are capable to donate blood". But its showing an error "non well formed numeric value encountered". as i am beginner its a big issue for me. expecting your help. thanks in advance.

**here is my code**

```
 <?php 

                   $date= Session::get("donation_date");
                   if (isset($date)) {
                        $today= time();
                        $difference=($date- $date) > 1;
                        echo ' '.$difference.' you are capable to donate blood';
                   }


              ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using Unix time on one hand and a string on the other.
Unix time is a sends counter and has a value as integer.
The date is (I assume) something like 2019-03-17, a string.

You can use strtotime to parse the date to Unix, that way you have two integers that can be subtracted.
The result is the difference in seconds, meaning 86400 is a day (disregarding DST).

```
$date= Session::get("donation_date");
if (isset($date)) {
    $today = time();
    $difference = $today - strtotime($date);
    if ($difference > 864000) echo ' '.$difference.' you are capable to donate blood';
}
```

Edit: for strtotime to be able to parse the date then it must be a parsable format.
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php
If it's not, then just say so and I will help you parse the date.

Comment: @MimHsan no problem! But keep in mind the code will differ on daylight savings days +- 1 hour. But I assume it's not that exact when people can donate blood. Feel free to accept the answer of it helped you.

Comment: Sorry i thought it is working. But unfortunately its not working.

Comment: Ok.. can you be more specific?

Comment: before its showing you are capable to donate blood. but now there is no such message. and there is no error. after login there is no such message

Comment: I can't debug your code. You need to help me. What are the values of the variables?

Comment: i dint get you. but for the date it is timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo:

```
$difference=($date-$date) > 1;
```

should be:

```
$difference=($today-$date) > 1;
```

Also, it would probably be best to ensure that `$date` is of the proper format, update:

```
if (isset($date)) {...}
```

to:

```
if (is_numeric($date)) {...}
```

as `$date` is always set as it is assigned directly above.
Hope that helps,